# tomcat starts in terminal but not running in browser on ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I manually installed tomcat7.

It runs on terminal (tomcat started).

But when I try to run it on browser(localhost:8080), page html appears.

I can't find where is the problem

> java version "1.7.0_79" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5)
>   (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02,
>   mixed mode)
>
> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat/
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat//temp
>
> Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
>
> Using CLASSPATH:
>   /opt/tomcat//bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat//bin/tomcat-juli.jar Tomcat
>   started.

Thank you

Comment: are you sure you are hitting tomcat on the right port?

Comment: locate Locate server.xml in {Tomcat installation folder $CATALINA_HOME}\ conf \ and see Connector element port value, something like '<Connector port="8080" ... '

Comment: in case you want to see more on the terminal when tomcat starts, don't use `startup.sh`, rather use `catalina.sh run`. This will show the actual log in the foreground. In addition, you say you see a html page - it might be delivered by tomcat, just not of the webapplication that you expect?

Answer (score 4):

If any error occur during tomcat startup time then that tomcat error is not shown on ubuntu terminal. So you need to check log file from following location.

```
{tomcat path}/logs/catalina.{date}.log
```

`{tomcat path}` = tomcat install path.
 `{date}` = log of date.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, now this may sound silly, but this problem occurred with me also. After a lot of brainwork, I came to this solution.

just add `sudo` before `./startup.sh`

Start tomcat server by the following command from the Tomcat `bin` directory as:

`$ sudo ./startup.sh`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the JAVA Environment is set properly; It needs Java to be running on the box.

Answer (score 0):

Check for these details :

**1) Tomcat is running on which port**

a) Check through netstat command if you know tomcat's PID  : 
For example, I can see the PID of my tomcat is 1483. So using,

`$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 1483` 
I can see on which port it is running / using.

b) Inside tomcat : Check for this line in server.xml under conf directory inside tomcat :
`<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

**2) Check whether you have enabled Proxy settings in browser.**

**3) Check whether you can access it via localhost or ip address or machine name.**
e.g. http://localhost:8080  , http://pc-name:8080, http://192.168.1.1:8080

4) Lastly, **check for firewall / iptables** and if possible, disable it temporarily and then try again or add in exceptions in firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Check your download version of tomcat. if you open your extracted tomcat file folder,you must see log folder. else it's may be you install apache-tomcat-**src**.tar.gz. if your file path shows src, its not give you a log file. so delete tomcat folder and download apache-tomcat-8.tar.gz correct file. now install it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache tomcat8.0.27 and lower does not work in jdk 9 change it to lower version. As of oct 2018. Results may change for updated version of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I've seen some answers online that suggest it's because it's not executed with the root user's privileges. However, you will find that this doesn't work. It still shows r the following error:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/loacl/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   
./catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/loacl/java/bin/java: not found
```

If at this point you print the JAVA_HOME variable and the PATH variable, you will see that this is not the same as what you set when you installed the JDK and Tomcat earlier.

Also, we find that the `java` command cannot be found.

```
java -version
找不到命令 “java”，但可以通过以下软件包安装它：
apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.18+10-0ubuntu1~22.04, or
apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72build2
apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.6+10-0ubuntu1~22.04
apt install openjdk-18-jre-headless  # version 18.0.2+9-2~22.04
apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-0ubuntu3~22.04
apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u362-ga-0ubuntu1~22.04
```

That's because you used the `su root` command instead of the `su - root` command.

> Compare the `su` and `su -` commands: `su` switches
> the user's access, but does not get the environment variable, so PATH
> is not brought in;`su -` is the full switching user, changing
> the working directory and getting environment variables, so you can
> find JAVA_HOME.
>
> When we use the normal `su` command to switch from one user to
> another, the current directory remains the same as the previous user.
>
> When we use the `su -` command to switch from one user to
> another, the current directory is changed to the target user's home
> directory.
>
> The `su` command does not create a new user environment, but
> rather the `su -` command creates a completely new user
> environment.

Switch to superuser with `su - root` command, enter your user password (if you have one), go to the `apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin`  directory, and execute the `startup.sh` jscript file to start Tomcat. The following result will be displayed.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   
Tomcat started.
```

Check if the Tomcat process is running.

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

> root        9524    1084 11 21:49 pts/2    00:00:03
> /usr/local/java/bin/java
> -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/conf/logging.properties
> -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
> -Dcatalina.base=/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87 -Dcatalina.home=/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/nzwl2020/apache-tomcat-8.5.87/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
> root        9558    9442 0 21:49 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java

```
netstat -anp | grep 8080
```

> tcp6    0   0     :::8080      :::*   LISTEN  9524/java

Turn off the firewall.

```
ufw disable
```

Visit `http://localhost:8080` in your browser (of course, your Tomcat's port may not be 8080).